plotly scatterplot on top of annotation
Any way to get an annotation below/under a scatter plot, so that the scatter-points show on top of the annotation text/link?
I tried with zorder=100 in scatter, but there is no zorder in add_annotation()
Below are the annotation and the scatter settings:
for i,px in enumerate(data['xpos']):
  nice = timegraph['nice'][i]
  fig.add_annotation(
    x=px, xshift=10, y=0, yshift=80, 
    text=f"<a href=\"{data['urls'][i]}\" alt=_blank>{px} - {nice}</a>", 
    textangle=270, bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
  )
  fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
      x=data['xpos'],
      y=timegraph['ygrid'],
      yaxis="y2",
      name="Total Testrun Time",
      marker={'color': 'gray', 'size': 15},
      text=timegraph['nice'],
      mode='markers'
    )
  )

The gray scatter-points on the 4 leftmost bars are below the annotated timestamp and not showing, I hold the mouse on the point and get the gray legend:


A workaround is to use opacity:
  fig.add_annotation(
    x=px, xshift=10, y=0, yshift=80, 
    text=f"<a href=\"{data['urls'][i]}\" alt=_blank>{px} - {nice}</a>", 
    textangle=270, bgcolor="#FFFFFF", opacity=0.5
  )


